# Extending REST API responses

Tags: rest-api

I have a custom post type with a parent post, and code to fetch this post in Javascript via a `GET` request, all is working very well. The API endpoints I'm using are those provided by core when `show_in_rest` is set to true on registration.

However, I want a little more information about the parent post than its ID, and I don't want to make a second request to fetch it, **so how might I extend the response from the REST API to include that information**? Or any other arbitrary information for that matter.

In particular it would be great to include the title and URL, but a full post object would be good too. Note that I do not want to create a custom endpoint from scratch, but extend the existing core endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the response data via the [`rest_prepare_{$this->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_this-post_type/) filter, like so for a custom post type `test_cpt` (registered with `hierarchical` and `show_in_rest` set to `true`):

```
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_test_cpt', 'rest_prepare_test_cpt' );
function rest_prepare_test_cpt( WP_REST_Response $response ) {
    $data = $response->get_data();

    if ( ! empty( $data['parent'] ) ) {
        if ( ! $parent_post = get_post( $data['parent'] ) ) {
            return $response;
        }

        // Include only some post data.
        $data['parent_data'] = [
            'title'   => get_the_title( $parent_post ),   // or just $parent_post->post_title
            'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt( $parent_post ), // or just $parent_post->post_excerpt
            'link'    => get_permalink( $parent_post ),
        ];

        // Or include the whole data..
        // $data['parent_data'] = $parent_post;             // object
        // $data['parent_data'] = $parent_post->to_array(); // array

        $response->set_data( $data );
    }

    return $response;
}
```

`WP_REST_Response` extends `WP_HTTP_Response` which defines the `get_data()` and `set_data()` methods.

Note that the code may not work if you set a different `rest_controller_class` when you register the post type. (The default controller class is `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` which fires the filter used above)

Comment: That looks awesome :) Let me give it a quick try out at my end before I accept else I think we're on to a winner

Comment: So, how was it? All good? :)

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test yet

Comment: Success! It worked!

Comment: Awesome! (sorry if I bothered your weekend.. heh)